Let's formulate our Cryptocurrency Close-Reason!
As you might have read, we got asked to formulate our Cryptocurrency close reason. Unfortunately, the short texts you are used to are a thing of the past as we can now have audience-specific formulations!
Of course, this means we need a concrete text to fill in, so please provide one full formulation per answer and vote on how you feel about each of them.

Guidelines on interacting with answers in this Q&A:

Upvote if you actively like a formulation
Don't vote if you can live with it, and have no strong feelings in either direction about it
Downvote if you actively dislike the formulation
Comment to suggest minor improvements that keep the spirit of the formulation close enough and are likely to increase the quality

Guideslines on writing answers in this Q&A:
Each answer needs to provide the following five parts (full example & details here, Academia.SE's full set):

A brief description (10-100 chars) This will be the headline of the close reason, similar to "Duplicate" or "Needs more focus"
Usage guidance (25-500 chars) This will be shown in the voting / flag to close dialog
Public post notice description (25-500 chars) This will be shown to everyone after the question is closed
Post owner guidance (25-500 chars) This is additional info that will be shown only to the asker after the question is closed
Privileged user guidance (25-500 chars) This is additional info that will be shown only to users with close / reopen privileges after the question is closed

Plus, ideally, explanations / justifications / similar for formulations.
It is also explicitly encouraged to copy (some / most) formulations from other answers if you think you found a better variant / better sub-part (attribution is also encouraged though).

It seems we have found the desired wording. It will be enacted along with the update to our other three close reasons. Until then, I'm leaving this meta Q&A up so anyone can still suggest improvements.

Also don't forget to follow this questions and / or its answers if you want to stay up to date as this will probably see some activity which in some cases might cause you to change your vote, e.g. to promote a new, better formulation over one you only previously liked.

Brief Description

Cryptocurrency, not Cryptography

Finding a few words that encapsulate the sentiment of this close reason is tricky. This is my attempt to encapsulate that cryptocurrency is not always cryptography while keeping the sentiment that we only ban questions about non-cryptographic aspects.
Usage Guidance

The question - unshiftably at its core - asks about a non-cryptographic aspect of cryptocurrencies in general or one specific one. This could be financial, economic, or legal aspects, or it could be about usage, recovery, or non-cryptographic operation of tools, websites, or smart contracts. If it is about about a cryptocurrency with a dedicated network site like Bitcoin or Ethereum, consider flagging for migration instead.

Thanks to Aman Grewal for the suggestion on the formulation.
This essentially uses the wording from the prior question, enriched with a request for migration flagging when appropriate. It should be comprehensive enough to give voters a good idea of what we are looking for. The "unshiftably at its core" is meant to be short for "you can't re-focus this question to ask about a cryptographic aspect instead without completely dropping what the original asker was looking for".
Public Post Notice Description

This question was closed because it asks about a non-cryptographic aspect of cryptocurrencies. It is not currently accepting answers. For details on our policy see our normative meta discussion.

Thanks to LWChris for the suggestion on the formulation.
This is kept intentionally simple. Stating that we don't accept non-cryptographic questions even if they relate to cryptocurrencies and then pointing people to where we decided this. I don't know what else we should tell a random bypasser here or somebody who can't place a vote to re-open or similar.
Post Owner Guidance

If this question is about a mechanism for a popular cryptocurrency with its own site on the network, please ask there instead, for a helpful list, see our help center. If you think your question is actually about underlying cryptographic aspects of cryptocurrencies, please edit it to clarify potentially missleading aspects. Note that recovery and usage of tools, websites and smart contracts do not qualify as cryptographic aspects.

This one tries to have a helpful tone. Pointing the poster to dedicated cryptocurrency sites when available and then asking them to trim the question down / clarify if it is actually about a cryptographic aspect. At the same time it clarifies that things that might look cryptographic, like using it / recovering wallets is actually not.
Privileged User Guidance

If you believe this question should be migrated to a dedicated cryptocurrency site, please flag for migration, a list is in our help center. If you believe that the focus of this question can be shifted to a cryptographic aspect while retaining some use to the original asker, please help by editing it or leaving a guiding comment.

These are the things a privileged user can do to help salvage the question, I'm not sure what else to put here - which would probably also be helpful on the post owner notice.

The second sentence in Usage Guidelines is a bit of a mess. I suggest "This could be financial, economic, or legal aspects, or it could be about recovery, non-cryptographic operation, tools, websites, or smart contracts."

The "Public Post Notice Description" confuses me. What does not accept answers? The question, or the meta discussion? "It" as a pronoun should relate to the latest noun, which in this case would be the "meta discussion". Consider swapping 2nd and 3rd sentence: This question was closed ... It is not currently accepting answers. For details on our policy see ....
